# Weighted interval scheduling solution construction

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am following tardos book to learn dynamic programming. I have a doubt in the solution construction part of weighted interval scheduling problem.
It is suggested that instead of using another array to store the solution, we should use the same cost array in this way :

```
Find-Solution(j)
 if  j = 0 then 
   output nothing
 else
   If Vj + M[p(j)] >= M[j-1] then
    output j together with the result of find-solution(p(j))
 else
   output find-solution(j-1)
 endif
```

My problem is that to find p(j) it should take O(n) time, and we can make these recursive calls O(n) time making this algorithm O(n^2). But in book it is claimed that this is O(n).
Also we are doing pretty much the same calculation we did to find the cost array m again. is there a way to eliminate this. If I want to use an array to store solution, what should I store in that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think their analysis is assuming that you have precomputed all values of p and in that case the runtime of the method is indeed O(n). Computing the values of p though will take O(n log n).

See how to compute p here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4820/2010su/handouts/computation-of-p-j.pdf

To see similar analysis about the algorithm: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa08/cs473/Lectures/lecture12.pdf. There it also claims that the computation takes O(n). But you will see in the end his analysis of the total running time including computing p is O(n log n).

Comment: ya that precomputed thing looks correct. thanks for clearing this.

Answer (score 2):

Finding `p[1..j]` will take O(n log n) runtime complexity:

- you have to compute it for every interval in 1..j: O(n)
- for each interval you will have to find rightmost mutually compatible (non-overlapping) interval: O(log n) with binary search

And since both O(n) and O(log n) are growing (when n grows), we have to take product as our final complexity, that's why finding all p[1..j] is O(n log n).

Now, on find-solution: it is O(n) because it assumes the pre-computed values. And it is quite logical, as we want to concentrate on OPT traversal in this method, and are not interested in how p(j) were calculated.

Finally, when we have several Big-Oh computations, and need to find their sum, the *dominant function* defines the total complexity. That's if in our case we have:

- O(n log n) to find p[1..j]
- O(n) to find actual intervals with find-solution()
- O(n log n) to sort intervals by finishing time
- O(n) to build OPT[1..j] iteratively

their sum will be dominated by O(n log n):

O(n log n) + O(n) + O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)

Therefore the overall algorithm performance is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
import bisect
import time
from datetime import datetime

"""
Weighted Interval scheduling algorithm.
Runtime complexity: O(n log n)
"""

class Interval(object):
    '''Date weighted interval'''

    def __init__(self, title, start, finish):
        self.title = title
        self.start = int(start)
        self.finish = int(finish)
        self.weight = self.finish - self.start

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.title, self.start, self.finish, self.weight))


def compute_previous_intervals(I):
    '''For every interval j, compute the rightmost mutually compatible interval i, where i < j
       I is a sorted list of Interval objects (sorted by finish time)
    '''
    # extract start and finish times
    start = [i.start for i in I]
    finish = [i.finish for i in I]
    print start
    print finish
    p = []
    for j in xrange(len(I)):
        i = bisect.bisect_right(finish, start[j]) - 1  # rightmost interval f_i <= s_j
        print j, i
        p.append(i)

    return p

def schedule_weighted_intervals(I):
    '''Use dynamic algorithm to schedule weighted intervals
       sorting is O(n log n),
       finding p[1..n] is O(n log n),
       finding OPT[1..n] is O(n),
       selecting is O(n)
       whole operation is dominated by O(n log n)
    '''

    I.sort(lambda x, y: x.finish - y.finish)  # f_1 <= f_2 <= .. <= f_n
    p = compute_previous_intervals(I)

    # compute OPTs iteratively in O(n), here we use DP
    OPT = collections.defaultdict(int)
    OPT[-1] = 0
    OPT[0] = 0
    for j in xrange(1, len(I)):
        OPT[j] = max(I[j].weight + OPT[p[j]], OPT[j - 1])

    # given OPT and p, find actual solution intervals in O(n)
    O = []
    def compute_solution(j):
        if j >= 0:  # will halt on OPT[-1]
            if I[j].weight + OPT[p[j]] > OPT[j - 1]:
                O.append(I[j])
                compute_solution(p[j])
            else:
                compute_solution(j - 1)
    compute_solution(len(I) - 1)

    # resort, as our O is in reverse order (OPTIONAL)
    O.sort(lambda x, y: x.finish - y.finish)

    return O

if __name__ == '__main__':
    I = []
    I.append(Interval("Summer School" , "2", "10"))
    I.append(Interval("Semester 1" , "1", "9"))
    I.append(Interval("Semester 2" , "11", "15"))
    I.append(Interval("Trimester 1" , "15", "20"))
    I.append(Interval("Trimester 2" , "14", "21"))
    I.append(Interval("Trimester 3" , "4", "11"))
    I.append(Interval("Trimester 4" , "15", "22"))
    O = schedule_weighted_intervals(I)
    print O
```